# Align picture next to video embedding on a markdown document

Tags: html, css, markdown, jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to place an image next to a video embedded from YouTube in my markdown document, using the following syntax

```
<iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2qXhBIHlfaM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<img src="/pictures/colour_bar.png" width="200" height="315" align="right" />
```

It turns out that the image is under the video like:

[image: this]

Can someone please tell me how I can place this image next to the video in the markdown document using html?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the iframe has its own line is that an iframe defaults to 'display: block' (and a img element defaults to 'display: inline'). I would suggest to add the style/CSS 'display: inline-block' to both elements, like this:

```
<iframe style="display: inline-block;" width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2qXhBIHlfaM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><img style="display: inline-block;" src="/pictures/colour_bar.png" width="200" height="315" />
```

If this does not work there is probably too little space to fit them next to each other on the page. You could make them smaller, like this:

```
<iframe style="display: inline-block;" width="225" height="162" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2qXhBIHlfaM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><img style="display: inline-block;" src="/pictures/colour_bar.png" width="100" height="162" />
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested by adding the style parameter, it still appears on two lines.

Comment: Can I see your code? Because the current code in a codepen shows them next to each other: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNPVoZ

Comment: `<iframe style="display: inline-block;" width="350" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2qXhBIHlfaM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<img style="display: inline-block;" src="/pictures/colour_bar.png" width="200" height="315" align="right" />`

Comment: it is still under the video.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it appears that the width of the video plus the width of the image is greater than the width of the page. That being the case, the image will wrap around to the next line and never appear beside the video. You need to change the size of something (video, image, and/or page).

Comment: @JoostS: By removing "align = right" the color bar comes right below the video.

Comment: @Waylan: I tried changing the size of the video, the color bar still shows up below the video.

Comment: Still does not work, video and image is smaller and one image is below the other.

Comment: Please look at this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNbqVR. It does work. If you are not willing to share your code, there is not much more I can do for you (or anybody else). Know that those two lines of HTML are NOT your code.

Comment: Here is the web page http://adityanagara.github.io/vaisala-weather-data and the code is available here https://github.com/adityanagara/adityanagara.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2016-02-28-Vaisala-Open-Weather-Data-Challenge.md Note: I have reverted it back to originally how it was but the image still is below the video with the above code in the .md document.

Comment: The problem is the new line after the iframe. It causes the markdown editor to wrap the image element in a (new) paragraph. I have updated my answer so this does not happen (removed the new line). Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML table

```
<table><tr><td style="width:50%">
<iframe width="450" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2qXhBIHlfaM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></td>
<td style="width:50%">
<img src="/pictures/colour_bar.png" width="200" height="315"/>
</td></tr></table>
```